# Github webhook URL config issue? How to fix it?

Tags: github, jenkins

I am using  GitHub project repository for build trigger from Jenkins.

The intention is when even code push done in GitHub repository project my Jenkins build should trigger automatically.

Steps done:

- Create Jenkins job for build trigger
- Config the setup on that particular job

  - Source Code Management management selected Git and updated Repository URL which I got from GitHub project code and have updated `https` Git URL
  - updated the GitHub credentials
  - Build trigger option
- I have selected *Build when a change is pushed to GitHub*
- then GitHub have update the webhook from setting
- I have added the webhook URL like http://ABCDEFGH123:8080/github-webhook/
- and selected `Content type` is `application/json`

While updating the webhook URL it shows the error message:

> We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't resolve host name

See the screenshot for reference. Please have a look. Please share the solution. Why am I unable to update the webhook URL? How to fix it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcR2g.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbpSm.jpg]

Comment: Is your Jenkins host name publicly available and reachable from GitHub?

Comment: Yes it's reachable

Comment: Posted my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75406406/2029134, make sure you check your jenkins log to see the error, if any

Answer (score 3):

Couple of reasons for this to happen.

1. If your running it locally --> it means that your URL is not exposed to the internet.So you can expose it to the Internet using
   ngrok (becareful as it exposes you (port) to the internet)
2. Corporate case-->Will most definitely be a proxy or firewall issue.So you can again use ngrok with proxy settings/Bypass your
   firewall, a bit of googling on how to do it will help.
3. You have an Enterprise Git Repo and are still unable to hit the webhook Go to Manage Jenkins --> Configure System-->GitHUB under
   that you would have mentioned your GitHub Server details, Under
   that, there is an Advance button, Further under is another Advance
   button click that. Add another URL for webhook or use the existing
   one which you would have mentioned.

The neat little feature this provides is that it tests your connection with GitHub and provides you with the reason why it failed.

Hope this helps, took me a long time to figure this out :0

Answer (score 0):

Either firewall is blocking or you've to check if WebHook is enabled in Github from *Repository -> Settings -> WebHooks*. There is a nice guide [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/). Use [RequestBin](https://requestb.in/) for testing to make sure that its not a server side issue :)