# Automatic build with Jenkins and GitLab

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I deploy Jenkins and GitLab using Docker (locally), both are connected with each other.

- One of the problems (*not very important*) is with SSH. I create ssh key inside Jenkins container and set it to GitLab, but when Jenkins try to checkout the repository throws "Permission Denied". So, executing Jenkins bash, try to run git command and what's happen? GitLab container needs a password for access. Searching, and trying to do as a virtualized server, no works. Whatever, I solved using user and password (I don't like, but works).
- The important problem. I don't have any problem creatin, and running, a job (using pipelines). The job download the world from GitLab and send the result to GitLab. The problem, after add a webhook with Jenkins URL to GitLab, push something but nothing happens in Jenkins, not trigger the job.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your webhook working correctly ?? are you able to send/receive request and response, if not refer to
[Github webhook URL config issue? How to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487563/github-webhook-url-config-issue-how-to-fix-it/49441937#49441937)

When you push does it trigger a request ? can you try hitting it with postman if you do have a request. If you can provide more information, then it will be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks. Solved my problem checking Jenkins security configuration.