# Couldn't connect host server

Tags: git, webhooks

I have created a jenkins-pipeline job to trigger on pull-request.
and i created webhook to configure the github with jenkins. But the webhook shows "last delivery was not successful, couldn't resolve host name". I kept https://

Comment: http://<jenkisipaddress>:8080/ghprbhook/  (pull_request)

Comment: The job is not getting trigger.

Comment: Is `<jenkinsipaddress>` accessible from outside of your network? If it's a 192.168.x.y address it won't be. (There are other addresses that aren't either, but 192.168.x.y is probably the most common.)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42487563/github-webhook-url-config-issue-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Let me try this thanks.