# GitHub webhook repo is unable to trigger jenkins pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks

Our Company used to self-host GitLab for source-code management and configured webhook on gitlab to trigger all the project pipelines on jenkins. Initially, the gitlab url was 'https://git.fulcrumdigital.com' and later for an upgraded version, they changed url to 'https://autobuild.fulcrumdigital.com'

Recently, we migrated to 'github.com' and created an organization. The source codes for various projects are found under this organization, which is private. Now, when I try to configure webhooks for these projects, I see that they deliver as intended to jenkins, but jenkins doesn't trigger the respective project's build. Instead, it gives out a message as shown below.
[jenkins-github webhook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8wUg.jpg)
I don't find any info regarding this webhook on global configuration page.

Here is a snapshot of jenkins logs
[jenkins logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vShfx.jpg)

I don't face this webhook issue for newly created pipeline-projects on jenkins. I face this issue for older pipeline-projects that already had their webhook configured earlier for gitlab.

Help me to resolve this issue and make jenkins trigger build from github webhook for older pipeline-projects.

Comment: Find some troubleshooting steps here: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/224621648-GitHub-Webhook-Troubleshooting

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve your question. E.g. include the errors as text instead of pictures to make it easier for others to copy them.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try force regenerating the webhooks?

Go to `Manage Jenkins > Configure System > GitHub plugin > Advance > Re-registers hooks for all jobs.`

Comment: I tried re-registering hooks for all jobs. I get a text saying "Works only when jenkins manages hooks(one or more specified)"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself. The first thing you want to do is go to `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` scroll down to the GitHub section and click on "Advanced". You will see this:

[image]

It's important to have access to your Jenkins log (I'm running Jenkins with Docker). When I clicked on `Re-register hooks for all jobs`, I got the following error:

[image: Error in jenkins]

In my case, the error mentioned something with my access token. So, I checked my Github personal access token and it turned out, I need to turn on `Read and Write` for Webhook:

[image: Turn on read write for webhook access]

Now, go back to Jenkins and click on `Re-register hooks for all jobs` again, and on the next push, the build was automatically triggered.